# Read byte[] from BlobUrl in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I made a BlobUrl from a Canvas element on my main / DOM thread like this:

```
 canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      photo.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
```

I send the BlobUrl to my WebWorker.  How can I read the byte array in my WebWorker using just BlobUrl?  *(I am trying to avoid unnecesary copies)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid copies, use transferrables.